# Border around the image within an NSImageView

Tags: swift, nsimage, nsimageview

I have an `NSImageView` which contains an image. Is there a simple way to draw a border around just the image (which might be smaller than the NSImageView), and not the entire NSImageView?

Comment: How would I do that programmatically?

Comment: I was able to get it done by using a wrapper view, and setting a border on the inner view. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, making a new image would also be an overhead. I wanted a simple solution. And I don't think most apps need to "draw" using code anymore, given the graphic-rich world of icons, images etc we live in.

Answer (score 0):

[Answering my own question.]

On the off chance that someone comes cross this page looking to get something similar done, a simple way to do it is by using a wrapper view, and setting a border on the inner view.